# How to change css which is in pub/static folder

Tags: magento2, css

I want to change the css which comes from this file `/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css/styles-m.css`
As we cannot change content in this file, then how can i change the css. Is there any way to override this file. If yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

The files under `/pub/static/` are generated, to change that css, you have to create your custom `css` file, then you add your update as you need, So :

1. > app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
     <head>
         <css src="css/local-m.css" />
     </head>
   </page>
   ```
2. > app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Theme/web/css/local-m.css

   ```
   /*Your css goes here*/
   ```

   <sup>Note:</sup>

   Don't forget to deploy the static content after your changes:

   - clean the cache
   - clean `var/view_preprocessed` CONTENT
   - clean `pub/static` content
   - deploy the static content = `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: i have tried this with custom css but it gives me 404 error: Page not found error...it showing me in file view list but not access page error.

Comment: `404` on which page ? have you exactly followed my steps ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can.

Go to pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css

And Delete the file styles-m.css

Clear your browsers cache. (Keep Cache disable of Magento)

Reload.

A soft link will be generated. Any changes made in your module will reflect in pub/static